# Remove a user from jailkit

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I've set up jailkit to chroot ssh-users at my server.
The way I did it was to create a general user-account and then put it to jail with:

```
jk_jailuser -m -j /home/suppliers -v -s /bin/bash supplier_pi
```

Now I wonder how to fully remove the user from jailkit.
My first opinion was only to remove the users directory in the jailroot.

But if I try to create a user with the same name again, I got a message like:

```
useradd: user 'supplier_pi' already exists
user supplier_pi already exists in /home/suppliers/etc/passwd
user supplier_pi has a correct home directory and shell already
home directory /home/suppliers/./supplier_pi is already inside the jail
```

As I didn't find any option in `jk_jailuser` to remove an account from jail, I wonder how to do this in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the following:

Below your jailroot-directory you also have an `/etc` directory.
There are 2 files which keeps all the jailkit-user permission:

- ./etc/group
- ./etc/passwd

Additional to this, the "main"-Useraccount at your Server still exist for this user. It's credentials are in `/etc/passwd` and some other files.

**Here is how to remove from jailkit:**

remove entries of the entries for the given user-account in

- `<jailkitRoot>./etc/group` and
- `<jailkitRoot>./etc/passwd`
- then remove the home-directory of this user in the jail: `<jailkitRoot>./<userToRemove>`

> Unfortunately there is no command to do this in jailkit itself, so you have to manually edit those files

To **fully remove a user** from your Server, don't forget to remove the user-account which still exist:

```
userdel <username>
```

That's it.